# Unable to extract ADComputer identity from WMIObject

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm a super-noob when it comes to powershell. I've been able to extract the WMIobject win32_LogicalDisk info except for the ADComputer identity info. See my code and columns needed to populate. I keep getting a blank under user. Any thoughts?

```
$exportPath = "\\Server01\users\ohyeah\Downloads\testfolder"

$computers = Get-Content "\\Server01\users\ohyeah\Downloads\testfolder\computers.txt"

$driveinfo = Get-WMIobject win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computers -filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
@{Name="Size_GB"; Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},
@{Name="FreeSpace_GB"; Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},
@{Name="%_FreeSpace_GB"; Expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.freespace/$_.size)*100)}},
@{Name="User"; Expression={$(Get-ADComputer -identity $_ -Properties Description | ft -a Description)}},
@{Name="Date"; Expression={$(Get-Date -format 'g')}} 

$driveinfo | Out-GridView 
$driveinfo | Format-Table -AutoSize
$driveinfo | Export-Csv "$exportPath\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber -Append
```

SystemName  DeviceID    VolumeName  Size_GB FreeSpace_GB    %_FreeSpace_GB  User    Date

Comment: are you referring to the `User` calculated property? does the `expression` part of that line run correctly when you run it alone in your loop?

Comment: The `Get-WMIObject` sends on an object that contains the property PSComputer if I remember right. Try `-identity $_.PSComputer` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the computer name, via the SystemName property. Just pass that in directly.

You also cannot use that Format-Table in that calculated property that way, especially if all you are asking for is a single field property which is nothing but a note field.

Lastly, unless that description field is populated, it will be empty, also using that Description property is not part of the default list, you have to ask for it asking for all properties and then specific property.

Running this on a local domain joined host...

```
# This will give you the data in the Description property
Clear-Host

$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$driveinfo = Get-WMIobject win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computers -filter "DriveType=3" | 
Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
@{Name="Size_GB"; Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},
@{Name="FreeSpace_GB"; Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},
@{Name="%_FreeSpace_GB"; Expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.freespace/$_.size)*100)}},
@{Name="User"; Expression={$(Get-ADComputer -identity $_.SystemName -Properties *).Description}},
@{Name="Date"; Expression={$(Get-Date -format 'g')}} 

$driveinfo | Out-GridView


# This will give you the full DN of the computer object
Clear-Host

$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$driveinfo = Get-WMIobject win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computers -filter "DriveType=3" | 
Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
@{Name="Size_GB"; Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},
@{Name="FreeSpace_GB"; Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},
@{Name="%_FreeSpace_GB"; Expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.freespace/$_.size)*100)}},
@{Name="User"; Expression={$(Get-ADComputer -identity $_.SystemName -Properties Description)}},
@{Name="Date"; Expression={$(Get-Date -format 'g')}} 

$driveinfo | Out-GridView
```